# How to format hour to "12.30" instead of "12:30"?

Tags: excel, time, format

How to format hour to "12**.**30" instead of "12**:**30" (note the `:` instead of the `.`)?

The goal is to format every cell with a point (for separation).

Comment: I am genuinely curious. Is my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nevertheless the less this is not exactly what I was looking for: The INPUT should be 12.30 (what I type on the keyboard!) not 12:30. Please try it 12.30 instead of 12:30 in your keyboard and you will see the difference. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

## 1

Select the cells you wish to have formatted this way.

## 2

Right-click on them and select Format Cells.

## 3

Under the Custom Category (on the left) enter this format string in the Type field on the right:

```
h.mm
```

## 4

Click OK